# ZwQuerySystemInformation is Not working Properly

Tags: winapi

I tried FindProcessidByName with Kernel Mode Driver, sometimes ImageName.Buffer goes to NULL , because of this , when ImageName.Buffer goes to NULL I can not find process ids. Do you have any idea why ImageName.Buffer goes to NULL sometimes, sir ?

```
 typedef struct _SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO_L
    {
        ULONG                   NextEntryOffset;
        ULONG                   NumberOfThreads;
        LARGE_INTEGER           Reserved[3];
        LARGE_INTEGER           CreateTime;
        LARGE_INTEGER           UserTime;
        LARGE_INTEGER           KernelTime;
        UNICODE_STRING          ImageName;
        ULONG                   BasePriority;
        HANDLE                  ProcessId;
        HANDLE                  InheritedFromProcessId;
    }_SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO_L, *P_SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO_L;

HANDLE LSFindProcess(LPSTR name)
{
    NTSTATUS durum;
    ULONG retsize;
    HANDLE hProcid = -1;
    P_SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO_L pi;
    durum = ZwQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, NULL, NULL, &retsize); // request how much memory size we need.
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(durum) && durum !=STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
    {
        DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "LS : ZwQuerySystemInformation Failed 1 durum : %p \n",durum);
        return -1;
    }
    PVOID    memPtr;
    memPtr = ExAllocatePool(PagedPool, retsize);
    if (!memPtr)
    {
        DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "LS : ExAllocatePool Failed \n");
        return -1;
    }
    memset(memPtr, 0, retsize);// zero mem

    durum = ZwQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, memPtr, retsize, NULL);
    pi = (P_SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO_L)memPtr; // parselliyorz
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(durum))
    {
        DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "LS : ZwQuerySystemInformation Failed 2 durum : %p \n", durum);
        return -1;
    }
    while (pi->NextEntryOffset)
    {
        if (pi->ImageName.Buffer) //some process null if I dont use this I am getting BSOD.
        { 
            if (!_stricmp(pi->ImageName.Buffer, name))
            {
                DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "LS : name %ws , pid : %d  \n", pi->ImageName.Buffer, pi->ProcessId);
                hProcid = pi->ProcessId; // pid
                break; // foundedd
            }
        }

        pi = (P_SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO_L)((unsigned char*)pi + pi->NextEntryOffset);
    }
    DbgPrintEx(DPFLTR_IHVDRIVER_ID, DPFLTR_INFO_LEVEL, "LS :  LSFindProcess bitti \n");
    return hProcid;
}
```

Comment: Please review [MCVE].  Your question is not a programming language question, it is a Windows API question.

Comment: at first you need query/resize this information in loop - after you got requested buffer size - new processes/threads can be and when you second time call *ZwQuerySystemInformation* *retsize* can be already not large enough. at second `while (pi->NextEntryOffset)` is error - you lost last process in list always. need do {} while() loop here

Comment: also `ImageName` is `UNICODE_STRING` - it not mandatory to be 0 terminated. you need use `RtlEqualUnicodeString` for example here

Comment: also who will be free memory after you ? ExFreePoll not calling. so many errors in so small code

Comment: this code not completed I Will Free memory when this problem solved.

Comment: @LeftSpace - no no, you always must just write correct code in this part. always free memory. i point you to main your errors in code. you need fix it. really no any problem here. `ZwQuerySystemInformation` always working Properly. only errors in your code. nothing else

Comment: and `_stricmp(pi->ImageName.Buffer, name)` are `Buffer` is `char*` ? compiler not give you error here ?. any way you need use `RtlEqualUnicodeString` here instead of `_stricmp` and even `_wcsicmp`. with this and check `if (pi->ImageName.Buffer) ` not need

Comment: @RbMm No I didn't get any error from compiler NO (/WX-) but I will use RtlEqualUnicodeString currently I am writing my own code thanks for example code.

Comment: @LeftSpace - i think you use *c* compiler. if you use *c++* - it give you error on this.  any way `Buffer` is wide char string. and it can (allowed) to be 0, when length is 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ZwQuerySystemInformation is Not working Properly

this is of course false. api working properly. if you got wrong results, this is only due errors in code. in concrete code spinet exist several errors.

in kernel mode exist difference between *Zw* and *Nt* api - need understand which version need call, if both (like in this concrete case) is exported. if you know that previous mode is kernel mode - need use *Nt* version. if you don't know previous mode in this point(at compile time) or previous mode user mode - need use *Zw* version. however this is general note and will be not error always call *Zw*

the first serious error - this is how `ZwQuerySystemInformation` called - first time for query requested buffer size `retsize` (in code) and second time already with this buffer size. but between this calls new threads and processes can be spawn in system. as result returned buffer size can be already not large enough. correct solution - call this api in loop, while it return `STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH`

the second - memory always must be free. especially in kernel mode. say that code incomplete - no excuse. code can be incomplete and intermediate, but free memory after allocation always must be immediately inserted

else one critical error - `while (pi->NextEntryOffset)` loop - with this loop we always lost (not process) the last entry (last created process). need change this.

> if (pi->ImageName.Buffer) //some process null if I dont use this I am
>   getting BSOD.

the `ImageName` is `UNICODE_STRING` and need work with it respectively. in case `ImageName.Buffer` the `ImageName.Length` is also 0. the `UNICODE_STRING ImageName;` is correct. incorrect only how you use it.

`!_stricmp(pi->ImageName.Buffer, name); // ??`

the `pi->ImageName.Buffer` is `PWSTR` so it can not be used with `_stricmp` as a matter of principle. think you use *c* compiler - *c++* simply give you error here. but even use `_wcsicmp` is incorrect here - again `pi->ImageName` is `UNICODE_STRING` and need use `RtlEqualUnicodeString(&pi->ImageName, name, TRUE)` where name must be of course `PCUNICODE_STRING` but not `PCSTR` or `PSTR` or even `PCWSTR`. if you have `PCWSTR name` as input - you need wrap it to `UNICODE_STRING` before call this api. example of code:

```
NTSTATUS LSFindProcess(PCUNICODE_STRING ImageName, PHANDLE UniqueProcessId)
{
    ULONG cb = 0x20000;

    PVOID buf;
    NTSTATUS status;
    do 
    {
        status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;

        if (buf = ExAllocatePool(PagedPool, cb))
        {
            if (0 <= (status = NtQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation, buf, cb, &cb)))
            {
                union {
                    PVOID pv;
                    PBYTE pb;
                    PSYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION pspi;
                };

                pv = buf;
                ULONG NextEntryOffset;

                goto __0;

                do 
                {
                    pb += NextEntryOffset;
__0:
                    if (RtlEqualUnicodeString(&pspi->ImageName, ImageName, TRUE))
                    {
                        *UniqueProcessId = pspi->UniqueProcessId;
                        break;
                    }

                } while (NextEntryOffset = pspi->NextEntryOffset);
            }
            ExFreePool(buf);
        }

    } while (status == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH);

    return status;
}
NTSTATUS LSFindProcess(PCWSTR ImageName, PHANDLE UniqueProcessId)
{
    UNICODE_STRING us;
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&us, ImageName);

    return LSFindProcess(&us, UniqueProcessId);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

thanks for everyone especially @RbMm thanks for informations.
 Finished code I hope this post help someone..

```
/// <summary>
/// Struct SystemProcessInformation
/// </summary>

typedef struct _SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO_L
{
    ULONG                   NextEntryOffset;
    ULONG                   NumberOfThreads;
    LARGE_INTEGER           Reserved[3];
    LARGE_INTEGER           CreateTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER           UserTime;
    LARGE_INTEGER           KernelTime;
    UNICODE_STRING          ImageName;
    ULONG                   BasePriority;
    HANDLE                  ProcessId;
    HANDLE                  InheritedFromProcessId;
}_SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO_L, *P_SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO_L;

/// <summary>
/// Find Process ID By Name , thanks @RbMm
/// </summary>
/// <param name="imagename">Process name </param>
/// <param name="pid">Output Process id</param>
/// <returns>NTSTATUS.</returns>

NTSTATUS LSFindProcessIdByName(IN PCWSTR imagename, OUT PHANDLE pid)
{

    NTSTATUS durum = STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
    ULONG qmemsize = 0x1024;
    PVOID qmemptr = 0;
    P_SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO_L spi;
    UNICODE_STRING uimagename;
    RtlInitUnicodeString(&uimagename, imagename); // @RbMm
    *pid = -1;
    do
    {
        qmemptr = ExAllocatePool(PagedPool, qmemsize); // alloc memory for spi
        if (qmemptr == NULL) // check memory is allocated or not.
        {
            return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
        }
        durum = ZwQuerySystemInformation(SystemProcessInformation,qmemptr, qmemsize, NULL);
        if (durum == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH)
        {
            qmemsize = qmemsize * 2; // increase qmemsize for next memory alloc
            ExFreePool(qmemptr); // free memory
        }
    } while (durum == STATUS_INFO_LENGTH_MISMATCH); // resize memory
    spi = (P_SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO_L)qmemptr;

    while(1)
    {

        if (RtlEqualUnicodeString(&uimagename, &spi->ImageName, TRUE)) // @RbMm
        {
            *pid = spi->ProcessId;
            break;
        }

        if (spi->NextEntryOffset == 0)
            break;

        spi = (P_SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFO_L)((unsigned char*)spi + spi->NextEntryOffset); // next info 
    }

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(durum))
    {
        ExFreePool(qmemptr); // free memory
        return STATUS_UNSUCCESSFUL;
    }
    ExFreePool(qmemptr); // free memory 
    return STATUS_SUCCESS; 
}
```

Comment: `qmemsize = qmemsize * 2; ` you must not do this, but use the last parameter of `ZwQuerySystemInformation` - set it to `&qmemsize` - it return you actually required size, at this moment. may be exist sense after this increment it on constant size (say `qmemsize += 0x1000`) in case required size increased before next call.

Answer (score -1):

You should not be calling ZwQuerySystemInformation, it's not easily portable across Windows OS's and may not even be available on some of them. The [MSDN documentation for this function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725506(v=vs.85).aspx#SYSTEM_PROCESS_INFORMATION) recommends alternate functions for your particular usage.

Comment: what you mean under *it's not easily portable across Windows OS's* ? this is absolute false. this function exist in all windows versions with stable interface

Comment: @RbMm, not according to the [MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725506(v=vs.85).aspx), see the first line of the page right below the title.

Comment: what i wrote based not on any msdn docs (which special lie) but on huge experience. use this api from win2000 to up to latest win10. it not need any *port* stable interface which extended (added new information classes). this api is great worked

Comment: @RbMm: So you can personally guarantee that this function will work the same way in five years?

Comment: @RbMm, Microsoft doesn't even provide an import library for it.  Some of the structures it returns are literally subject to change without notice from Microsoft.

Comment: @jwdonahue - *Microsoft doesn't even provide an import library for it* - this is absolute lie again. *ntdll.lib* in user mode and *ntoskrnl.lib* in kernel mode. can i ask why you decide that no import library ?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand - i can confirm that until this function (say for concrete with `SystemProcessInformation` class) worked on all existing os and always give (if system not hooked) correct result. i use this api huge count of times, every day use it with this class

Comment: I know internal functions Can be removed without any notice and structs can be change every windows version its not problem my problem this function not capturing every process info some process running but information missing.

Comment: @LeftSpace - look for example on your while loop - you always lost the last process record in array

Comment: *is no longer available for use as of Windows 8.* - this is lie. **This function has no associated import library** - this is absolute and conscious lie (*ntdll.lib*, *ntdllp.lib* (extended version of prev lib), *ntoskrnl.lib*) exist in every wdk (early ddk) install- for what lie?

Comment: @RbMm: The question was: *"Can you personally guarantee, that this function will work the same way in five years?"* Any reason you didn't answer that question? Still having a hard time understanding the merits and concept of contracts? Your knowledge and experience will be a lot more valuable, once you do.

Comment: @IInspectable - can you personally guarantee on any winapi that it not changed in future, despite it documented ? simply example `GetVersion` and such api. or how changed comctl32 when migrated to 6.0 version. i don know what will be next day. but until this api is working properly in all windows versions. this is fact. fact and that in msdn exist conscious lie (say in part of not existing import lib). error result in OP code - only due huge count of personal errors in code

Comment: @RbMm: `GetVersion` still works as advertised way back. The common controls still work the way they always did. Version 6 is an **opt-in**. Code that wasn't changed to use version 6 still works as it always did. Yes, I'm fairly confident that I can rely on the published contract.

Comment: @IInspectable - but and `ZwQuerySystemInformation` **still works** in absolute same way, as it work in say win2000. this is simply fact. however semantic of `GetVersion[Ex]` is changed. early it always return actual windows version. unconditionally. now this already not true. so fanny that semi-documented `ZwQuerySystemInformation` absolute not changed, when some documented api like version api some changed

Comment: `GetVersion` was semantically changed in a way, that did not affect programs, that were written against that contract. The changes affect programs written today, against a new contract. The initial contract wasn't broken. Microsoft has an obligation to not change a published contract. `ZwQuerySystemInformation` does not have a published contract. It can be changed at any time, without prior notice. The point is moot, though, as you don't understand, what a contract is.